# What is mongodb equivalent for firebase onSnapshot to get realtime updates

Tags: mongodb, react-native, react-hooks

For firebase, there is onSnapshot to get new messages in a chat application and its written in the client side code inside useEffect.

*Purpose is - Let the server tell the client of new messages instead of client asking the server every second.*

```
useEffect(() => 
    onSnapshot(query(collection(db, 'matches', linkDetails.id, 'messages'), orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')), 
    snapshot => setMessages(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
        id: doc.id,
        ...doc.data()
    }))))
, [linkDetails, db])
```

What is the equivalent for mongodb to get new messages as soon as new messages are sent/received?
I have the messages in api - `/api/messages/get` which is the backend.

This is for react native and I do not use nextjs which has UseSWR.

Comment: At a glance, perhaps [Change Streams](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/) are what you are interested in?

Comment: Looks like Change Stream can monitor an entire collection which is probably a waste. The snapshot example above monitors linkDetails.id specifically. Looks like socket.io is the way to go but was hoping mongodb has something built in.

Comment: Does the example on that page where they limit the results to a specific username ([here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/#modify-change-stream-output)) satisfy your needs?